# smashoperator produces black line with Linux Libertine O

Tags: luatex, libertine, mathtools

When I use [fontspec](/questions/tagged/fontspec) to set the main font to "Linux Libertine O", the `smashoperator` command (and also `mathclap` and friends) produce a black line above the smashed subscript (with [luatex](/questions/tagged/luatex)).

[image: example of unwanted black line]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\[
    \smashoperator{\sum_{i \in \mathrm{longidentifier}}} f(i)
\]

\end{document}
```

The problem does not occur with other fonts like Times New Roman or Linux Biolinum O. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem boils down to the following. But I can't say if the font or the binaries (xetex has the problem too) is at fault as I have no idea what `\radical0` (use by `mathtools`) is supposed to do and why it is affected by a change of the operator font.

Imho the best would be to ask the authors of `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}\g_fontspec_encoding_tl\g_fontspec_mathrm_tl\mddefault\updefault
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\radical0 a$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get the line with `xelatex` (but I only have TL 2011 on the system I'm using).

Comment: @egreg: It also depends on the font. With an older version I didn't get the line either.

Comment: \radical combines a delimiter (first argument) with a horizontal line to create a square-root-like symbol. Apparently, giving 0 (=no delimiter) as argument usually disables also the horizontal line, except with the Libertine font. I reported this behavior to the mathtools author as well as in the Libertine [bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3555835&group_id=89513&atid=590374)